# how to delete single quotes but not apostrophes in perl

Tags: perl

I would like to know how to delete single quotes but not apostrophes in perl.

For example:

> 'It's raining again!'

print

> It's raining again!

Thanks so much

Comment: Your samples use the same character for both single quotes and apostrophes, the character defined by Unicode as `U+0027 APOSTROPHE`. I presume that was your intent, but there are also distinct single-quote characters in Unicode, `U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` and `U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`. You might want to update your question to make it clearer that all the characters are the apostrophe character (assuming that's what you meant).

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this without some natural language processing here's a complex case: 'It's so frustrating' she said 'the boys' toys are everywhere.'

Answer (score 4):

If you assume that a single-quote is always preceded or followed by whitespace, the following pair of regular expressions should work:

```
$line =~ s/\s'/ /g;  #preceded by whitespace
$line =~ s/'\s/ /g;  #followed by whitespace
```

you also need to account for if the string starts or ends with a single quote:

```
$str =~ s/^'//;  #at the start of a string
$str =~ s/'$//;  #at the end of a string
```

Comment: +1 but \s is white-space characters not only space (which is even better), you still have a problem with the plural possessives: the boys' toys.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky one. Some single quotes come after or before letters, but you want to remove only those between letters. Perhaps something like this, using negative lookarounds:

```
s/(?<![\pL\s])'|'(?![\pL\s])//g;
```

Which will remove *either* single quotes without letters or whitespace after or before it. Lots of negations to keep track of there. The expanded version:

```
s/
    (?<![\pL\s])'   # no letters or whitespace before single quote
    |               # or
    '(?![\pL\s])    # no letters or whitespace after single quote
//gx;
```

This will cover words like - as Eli Algranti pointed out in a comment - `boys' toys` and `that's`, but language is always tricky to predict. For example, it will be next to impossible to solve something like:

```
'She looked at him and said, 'That's impossible!''
```

Of course, if you expect your single quotes to appear only at end or beginning of string, you don't need to be this fancy, you can just remove the last and first character, with any means necessary. Such as, for example, as sputnik just suggested:

```
s/^'|'$//g;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (<DATA>) {
    s/(:?(^\s*'|'$))//g;
    print;
}
__DATA__
 'It's raining again!'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
It's raining again!
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

- *there's more one than one way to do it*
- `(:?)` prevent non-needed capture